# VS Code not opening in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Not a question but a solution to the issue that I experienced in troubleshooting VS Code. After following this post [vs code not opening up in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707561/vs-code-not-opening-up-in-windows/76469365#76469365?newreg=27533f91a2474b159243fe088cd5ceff) trying to find a solution all valid solutions but didn't work for me, until I found this solution myself.

The clean wipe of any visual studio related software including the Visual ++ Redistributable, reboot then reinstalling Visual Studio Community, reboot again, and the current version of Visual Studio Code 1.79. If you see this post in the future install whatever current version is released.

After all that VS Code finally opens. This was the 2nd to last resort I had to do before I had to decide whether to contact VS for support or rebuild windows entirely.

Hopefully this will help out anyone that get stuck like I did at that point.

Comment: Why didn't you post this as an answer to the original question you mentioned? You should answer it there and remove your "question" here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: [/help/self-answer](/help/self-answer), [answer], [ask] :)

Comment: I wanted to answer on the post but it didnt let me because Im too new to the site. This site had the solutions but didnt work until I found one on my own and wanted to share it so I decided to post it, so here we are. Lol I work IT as a profession feel free to post the answer on the post all I wanted was the solution I found to be out there.